# Predefined pffile url before saving

Tags: ios, parse-platform, aws-sdk, pffile

I want to save my files to aws and then use the URL of my Parse pffile to point to it. Is there a way to predefine a pffile's url before saving it?  Is it as easy as just accessing the pffile.url property? I'm not sure on this because I know it automatically generates a url when you upload a pffile with data.

Thanks!

Comment: Unlikely.  The purpose of the PFFile is to represent files parse manages for you.  What would be the benefit over hanging on to the AWS url yourself?

Comment: The file download times for parse are extremely slow - around 208 kb/s. So I want to put my files on aws and have parse keep managing the rest of my backend

Comment: yes, my question is why get PFFile involved at all?